# Counter-example of an affirmation

Tags: examples-counterexamples

Does anyone know any example that invalidates the following affirmation:

> If a morphism $f:A\to A$ induces the identity $\hat f:\operatorname{Spec} \left( A \right) \to \operatorname{Spec} \left( A \right)$ then $f = \operatorname{id} _A $.